# aws cli version 2 install - "command not found" error

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

I am beginner to aws, i installed aws cli v2 on my linux machine using-

```
curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
unzip awscliv2.zip
sudo ./aws/install
```

After the install if i run aws --version i get

"Command 'aws' not found,"

my path has usr/local/bin

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

If i do

```
$ sudo /usr/local/bin/aws --version
aws-cli/2.5.6 Python/3.9.11 Linux/5.4.0-107-generic exe/x86_64.ubuntu.20 prompt/off
```

it works fine.

I added

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

to my .profile and ran . ~/.profile as well. But no luck.

Please help me.

Comment: could be a permission issue. What's the permission of `/usr/local/bin/aws`?

Comment: lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root         37 Apr 17 11:07 aws -> /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/current/bin/aws
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root         47 Apr 17 11:07 aws_completer -> /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/current/bin/aws_completer

Answer (score 1):

OP Here. What worked for me was

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/local/aws-cli
```

Don't know why AWS bundler could not do it.